# How to express the idea that "improve performance"

Tags: meaning

I want to express an idea that I "decrease app crash". But the sentence sounds weird.

> Fix app crash by 50 percent

How should I refactor this sentence.

Thanks

Comment: Would you not be satisfied with reducing it by half?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

**X reduces the rate of app crashes by 50%**

Good solid sentence. Nothing flashy or spectacular, but it gets the job done.

Comment: So it's not attractive. :'(
What expressions can attract me more?

Comment: What do you mean by "attractive"? Do you want your sentence to be more poetic? Because it's a mistake to make every sentence as "advanced" as possible.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is 'cut'.

> Cut app crash by 50 percent.

'app crash' is not desirable, so I guess the combination of solving or removing, and reducing or decreasing would be what you want to imply.